# How to get order items ids to get some product meta data?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I'm trying to extract item meta value from Woocommerce's orders by using:

```
$data = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item, '_tmcartepo_data', true );
```

However, I can't find a way to get order_item_id as the first parameter (using get_items)

```
global $woocommerce, $post, $wpdb;
$order = new WC_Order($post->ID);
$items = $order->get_items(); 

foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $item_id = $item['order_item_id']; //???
    $data = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_tmcartepo_data', true );
    $a = $data[0]['value'];
    $b = $data[1]['value'];
    echo $a;
    echo $b;
}
```

And I mean this order item_id (1 and 2)

[Order_item_id in database - Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8OJ7U.jpg)

How can I don that?

Thanks.

Comment: Please describe *when* this action fires - for instance: `woocommerce_checkout_create_order` hook fires before any DB interactions, so order items could not be accessed via $order->get_items().

Answer (score 30, accepted):

> **2018 Update:**
>
> - Clarifying the answer with 2 possible cases
> - Added compatibility for woocommerce 3+

**So There can be 2 cases:**

**1) Get product meta data** (not set in order item meta data):

You will need to get the product ID in the foreach loop for a `WC_Order` and to get some metadata for this product you wil use **`get_post_meta()`** function *( but NOT **`wc_get_order_item_meta()`** )*.

So here is your code:

```
global $post;
$order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
$items = $order->get_items(); 

foreach ( $order->get_items() => $item ) {

    // Compatibility for woocommerce 3+
    $product_id = version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ? $item['product_id'] : $item->get_product_id();

    // Here you get your data
    $custom_field = get_post_meta( $product_id, '_tmcartepo_data', true); 

    // To test data output (uncomment the line below)
    // print_r($custom_field);

    // If it is an array of values
    if( is_array( $custom_field ) ){
        echo implode( '<br>', $custom_field ); // one value displayed by line 
    } 
    // just one value (a string)
    else {
        echo $custom_field;
    }
}
```

---

**2) Get order item meta data** (custom field value):

```
global $post;
$order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
$items = $order->get_items(); 

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {

    // Here you get your data
    $custom_field = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_tmcartepo_data', true ); 

    // To test data output (uncomment the line below)
    // print_r($custom_field);

    // If it is an array of values
    if( is_array( $custom_field ) ){
        echo implode( '<br>', $custom_field ); // one value displayed by line 
    } 
    // just one value (a string)
    else {
        echo $custom_field;
    }
}
```

---

If the custom field data is an array, you can access the data in a foreach loop:

```
// Iterating in an array of keys/values
foreach( $custom_field as $key => $value ){
    echo '<p>key: '.$key.' | value: '.$value.'</p>';
}
```

**All code is tested and works.**

Reference related to data in orders:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/39409201#39409201) *(also for woocommerce 3)*
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. However, the $item['product_id'] only could get the order_id and it's not helpful for me. You can see my image above (http://i.stack.imgur.com/8OJ7U.jpg). All I can get is the product ID in meta_value column (number 90), but what I need is the number in order_item_id ( 1 or 2) so I can get the value of _tmcartepo_data meta_key. Any idea?

Comment: I'm currently get "Call to a member function get_items() on boolean" error for calling get_items() (WP 4.6.1 and WC 2.6.4). Trying to figure out why, but it seems you point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 6):

When doing the foreach on `$order->get_items()`, their key is actually the orderline ID. So:

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $key => $item ) {
    $data = wc_get_order_item_meta( $key, '_tmcartepo_data' );
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Late to the party, but being working with the same point with TM Extra Product Options plugin, I think this is what answers your question:

```
$order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
$items = $order->get_items();


foreach( $items as $item ){
    $data = unserialize($item['item_meta']['_tmcartepo_data'][0]);
    $a = $data[0]['value'];
    $b = $data[1]['value'];
    echo $a;
    echo $b;
}
```

Tested and works in my case.

Answer (score 0):

Use this `<pre><?php print_r($items); ?></pre>` to check all the contents of the $items array/object.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $key => $item ) {
$data = wc_get_order_item_meta( $key, '_tmcartepo_data' );
...
```

This solution was worth to me, change "_tmcartepo_data" for your meta_key.

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to get order items from database;

```
/**
 * @param $order_id
 *
 * @return array|null|object
 */
function get_order_items( $order_id ) {
    global $wpdb, $table_prefix;

    $items     = $wpdb->get_results( "SELECT * FROM `{$table_prefix}woocommerce_order_items` WHERE `order_id` = {$order_id}" );
    $item_name = array();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $item_name[] = $item->order_item_name;
    }

    return $item_name;
}
```