# Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

Reading up the changes in WooCommerce 3.0, it seems that is not possible to anymore properties from order items directly, so I would assume that the following code needs to be changed, since it is spitting out an error:

```
$order_item_id = 15;
$order_item = new WC_Order_Item_Product($order_item_id);
$return = $order_item->get_id() ? $order_item : false;
```

But, embarrassingly, I'm not sure how to change this code to use the correct new getter and setter functions in the newest version of this class, which no longer has a construct.  How to do this properly?  I don't see any `get` function on getting the order item in the same way as the above. 
 https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html

Maybe I am overlooking something here?

Answer (score 85, accepted):

> If you use the **`get_id()`** method, you get your item ID which is **`15`** in your code.

**Get the product ID:** 
The correct `WC_Order_Item_Product` method to get the Product Id is: **`get_product_id()`**

**Get the variation ID**: 
The correct `WC_Order_Item_Product` method to get the variation Id is: **`get_variation_id()`**

**Get the order ID** 
The correct `WC_Order_Item_Product` method to get the Order Id is: **`get_order_id()`**

**Get the WC_Product object** 
The correct `WC_Order_Item_Product` method to get `WC_Product` object is:
**`get_product()`**

**Get the WC_Order object** 
The correct `WC_Order_Item_Product` method to get `WC_order` object is:
**`get_order()`**

**Get and unprotecting the data and meta data** using [**`WC_Data`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html#_get_meta_data) methods:

- **`get_data()`**
- **`get_meta_data()`**

---

**Get The `WC_Product` object from the order item ID:**

```
$order_item_id = 15;
$item = new WC_Order_Item_Product($order_item_id);

// The product ID
$product_id = $item->get_product_id(); 

// The variation ID
$variation_id = $item->get_variation_id(); 

// The WC_Product object
$product = $item->get_product(); 

// The quantity
$quantity = $item->get_quantity(); 

// The order ID
$order_id = $item->get_order_id(); 

// The WC_Order object
$order = $item->get_order(); 

// The item ID
$item_id = $item->get_id(); // which is your $order_item_id

// The product name
$product_name = $item->get_name(); // … OR: $product->get_name();

// Get the product SKU (using WC_Product method)
$sku = $product->get_sku();

// Get line item totals (non discounted)
$total     = $item->get_subtotal(); // Total without tax (non discounted)
$total_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Total tax (non discounted)

// Get line item totals (discounted when a coupon is applied)
$total     = $item->get_total(); // Total without tax (discounted)
$total_tax = $item->get_total_tax(); // Total tax (discounted)
```

---

**Get the order items from the `WC_Order` object** *(and use the* `WC_product` *Object)*:

```
$order_id = 156; // The order_id

// get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// The loop to get the order items which are WC_Order_Item_Product objects since WC 3+
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){
    //Get the product ID
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();

    //Get the variation ID
    $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id();

    //Get the WC_Product object
    $product = $item->get_product();

    // The quantity
    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();

    // The product name
    $product_name = $item->get_name(); // … OR: $product->get_name();

    //Get the product SKU (using WC_Product method)
    $sku = $product->get_sku();

    // Get line item totals (non discounted)
    $total     = $item->get_subtotal(); // Total without tax (non discounted)
    $total_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Total tax (non discounted)
    
    // Get line item totals (discounted when a coupon is applied)
    $total     = $item->get_total(); // Total without tax (discounted)
    $total_tax = $item->get_total_tax(); // Total tax (discounted)
}
```

---

##### Accessing data and custom meta data:

**1). Unprotecting `WC_Order_Item_Product` data** and custom meta data:

You can use all [**`WC_Order_Item_Product data`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html) methods or you can unprotect the data using [**`WC_Data`**](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Data.html) following methods:

```
$order_id = 156; // The order_id

// get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// The loop to get the order items which are WC_Order_Item_Product objects since WC 3+
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){

    // Get the common data in an array: 
    $item_product_data_array = $item->get_data();

    // Get the special meta data in an array: 
    $item_product_meta_data_array = $item->get_meta_data();

    // Get the specific meta data from a meta_key: 
    $meta_value = $item->get_meta( 'custom_meta_key', true );

    // Get all additional meta data (formatted in an unprotected array)
    $formatted_meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data( ' ', true );


    // Get line item totals (non discounted)
    $total     = $item->get_subtotal(); // Total without tax (non discounted)
    $total_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Total tax (non discounted)
    
    // Get line item totals (discounted when a coupon is applied)
    $total     = $item->get_total(); // Total without tax (discounted)
    $total_tax = $item->get_total_tax(); // Total tax (discounted)
}
```

**2). The Array Access** is still possible *(for backwards compatibility with legacy arrays)* to get the common data directly:

```
$order_id = 156; // The order_id

// get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// The loop to get the order items which are WC_Order_Item_Product objects since WC 3+
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){

    
    $product_id    = $item['product_id']; // Get the product ID
    $variation_id  = $item['variation_id']; // Get the variation ID

    $product_name  = $item['name']; // The product name
    $item_qty      = $item['quantity']; // The quantity

    // Get line item totals (non discounted)
    $line_total     = $item['subtotal']; // or $item['line_subtotal'] -- The line item non discounted total
    $line_total_tax = $item['subtotal_tax']; // or $item['line_subtotal_tax'] -- The line item non discounted tax total

    // Get line item totals (discounted)
    $line_total2     = $item['total']; // or $item['line_total'] -- The line item non discounted total
    $line_total_tax2 = $item['total_tax']; // The line item non discounted tax total

    // And so on ……
}
```

---

As reference:

- [Get the metadata of an order item in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565643/get-the-metadata-of-an-order-item-in-woocommerce-3/48567687#48567687)
- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)

Comment: I'm not sure what this is doing.  mine is calling `get_id()` which I really don't know if that is the product id or some other object id.  Can you ellaborate on the difference, if any here?

Comment: Well, you seem to be returning the product id, but I believe I need to return the object, not the id...  `get_id()` just checks if it has an id, but the object is being returned not the product id.  And basically, I'm not sure if `get_id()` is possible to be used in this context.  Maybe this is fine, I have no idea, but I am getting a PHP Notice saying `wc_deprecated_function`

Comment: Great answer. May be ideal to name the $item variable to $product instead.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec: I can only say thank you for this and your other perfect and detailed answers. Without your help I and many others here would have disappeared in the WooCommerce swamp. :-)

Answer (score 2):

WC_Order_Item_Product inherits from WC_Order_Item, which has get_order_id(), so you can get the Order ID with

```
$order_item->get_order_id();
```

Comment: Is `get_order_id()` returning the same as `get_id()`.  Ohh, and thanks, I overlooked the inherited classes for some reason.  `get_id()` is coming from `WC_Data` which I believe is a different value than `get_order_id()` coming from `WC_Order_Item` class....

Comment: Right, I misread your question. Answer is almost the same though, like you saw, the get_id() method is also inherited from WC_Data. What error are you getting?