# WooCommerce If order status is in processing then products in that specific order will be hide from the shop

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders, stock

I have a shopping website with limited products. I'm looking for a solution in which, if Order status is "Processing", then Products in that specific Order remains hide from the Shop and Search result, unless Order status changed to Completed. (which means product is back in shop for purchase).

Moreover, all products will be sold individually.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec does this solution will work for me? [link]Auto restock products on specific order status changes in Woocommerce (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48910150/auto-restock-products-on-specific-order-status-changes-in-woocommerce)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hooks. Using these hook you will get 3 params called `$old_status`, `$new_status` and `$order_id`.
Then you just check is `$new_status` is `processing` or not. if processing then gets the order using `$order_id` and then create a loop for line_items. For each line item, you will get product_id and check the product is publish or not. If Publish then just make the product in draft status, if not then just continue the loop.

Like the same procedure, you can also check for Completed status. If the status is completed just loop through the order items and make each product draft to publish.

Hope you understand. If not, then let me know. I will share the code snippet

Comment: Hi, I have the same problem, but I don't undestand how to write the correct code, could you share the function ? Thanks