# Adding a custom field value to Woocommerce order email template

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, email-notifications

In Woocommerce with Advanced Custom Fields plugin, we have added a custom field to **products** and this field value is **specific** to each **product**.

Now I am trying to add this custom field value to our Woocommerce order confirmation emails.

I have tried the following code with no success:

```
<?php
    if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) {
        $order_id = int_val( $order->id ); // Older than 3.0
    } else {
        $order_id = int_val( $order->get_id() ); // 3.0+
    }

    $inst1 = get_field(‘how1’, $order_id );

    if( $inst1 ){
        echo '<p>' . $inst1 . '</p>';
    }
?> with Advanced Custom Fields plugin
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You are using a Wordpress function to get a WooCommerce field, and I'm 99% sure that's the problem. You need to use a WooCommerce function or class property to get the custom field. I don't know how the custom field plugin operates, but my guess would be you need to get the properties of the WooCommerce product using the WC_Product class.

Answer (score 1):

As your custom field **is specific to "product" post type** (but NOT to "order" post type) you need **to get first the order items** to get **the product ID** that you should use with ACF `get_field()` function this way:

```
<?php

    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get the product ID
        if ( version_compare( WC_VERSION, '3.0', '<' ) ) {
            $product_id = $item['product_id']; // Older than 3.0
        } else {
            $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // 3.0+
        }

        $inst1 = get_field( 'how1', $product_id );

        if( $inst1 ){
            echo '<p>' . $inst1 . '</p>';
        }
    }

<?
```

The custom field value will be displayed for each item in the order, as an order can have many items in it.

---

References:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3)