# Add Custom Field on 'Order Edit Page' showing 'Total Savings' in woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce, custom-fields

I need to calculate 'Total Saving' on an order in woocommerce. The code by @LoicTheAztec in answer for this question does that. [Display Custom Total Saving in generated invoice in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47639231/display-custom-total-saving-in-generated-invoice-in-woocommerce-3?rq=1)

He also answer to the custom field on order page in this question [Add custom field data to WooCommerce order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37766926/add-custom-field-data-to-woocommerce-order)

Now I need to display that 'Total Saving' on Order edit page as a 'Custom Field'
How to do that ? in short how to combine these two codes to show Total Savings on order edit page ?