# Get the metadata of an order item in woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

how to get metadata of a product woocommerce?
I have  field custom en my products and I need to get this data.

```
{"ID":151,
 "ORDER_ID":251,
 "NAME":"car",
 "PRODUCT_ID":87,
 "VARIATION_ID":0,
 "QUANTITY":1,
 "TAX_CLASS":"",
 "SUBTOTAL":"3",
 "SUBTOTAL_TAX":"0",
 "TOTAL":"3",
 "TOTAL_TAX":"0",
 "TAXES":{"TOTAL":[],
          "SUBTOTAL":[]},
 "META_DATA":[{"ID":1433,
               "KEY":"my_car",
               "VALUE":"red"}]}
```

But the always result is the same, I can't access to field `meta_data`. The field `ID` and `name` I have access.

I used `get_data()` and `get_item()`, but when I try access with `get_data()` to field  `meta_data` it give me this error:

```
 UNCAUGHT ERROR: CANNOT USE OBJECT OF TYPE WC_DATETIME AS ARRAY IN
```

And with `get_item()`, the value `meta_data` is null because is protected.

How can i get these values?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Try the following:

```
// Get the $order object from an ID (if needed only)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id);

// Loop through order line items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ){
    // get order item data (in an unprotected array)
    $item_data = $item->get_data();
    
    // get order item meta data (in an unprotected array)
    $item_meta_data = $item->get_meta_data();
    
    // get only All item meta data even hidden (in an unprotected array)
    $formatted_meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data( '_', true );

    // Display the raw outputs (for testing)
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($item_meta_data, true) . '</pre>';
    echo '<pre>' . print_r($formatted_meta_data, true) . '</pre>';
}
```

Related:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Answer (score 0):

```
/* Get Order Meta in Array[] format at thank you page - woocommerce */

add_action( 'woocommerce_thankyou', 'get_order_meta_at_thankyoupage', 20, 1);
function get_order_meta_at_thankyoupage( $order_id ){
  $orderr = wc_get_order($order_id);
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($orderr);
 echo '</pre>';
    
}
```