# Get woo-commerce meta data

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I have added the data by this code. It's inserted successfully. But how can I get the meta by function? I have tried with `get_post_meta()` but it's not working.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'add_custom_order_line_item_meta',10,4 );
function add_custom_order_line_item_meta($item, $cart_item_key, $values, $order){

    if(array_key_exists('course_name_one', $values) {

        $item->add_meta_data('Test ID',$values['course_name_one']);
      
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565643/get-the-metadata-of-an-order-item-in-woocommerce-3/48567687

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get the metadata of an order item in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565643/get-the-metadata-of-an-order-item-in-woocommerce-3)

Comment: Here's a good reference - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details