# Get protected custom order item meta data array from WooCommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, email, woocommerce, shopping-cart

I'am trying to use `woocommerce_get_order_item_totals` filter hook to add some extra information into the order totals (on orders and email notifications).

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'display_email_topay', 10, 2 );
function display_email_topay( $total_rows, $order ) {
    $total_rows['recurr_not'] = array(
       'label' => __( '2nd Installment:', 'woocommerce' ),
       'value'   => 'DATA NEEDS TO GO HERE' // <===
    );
    return $total_rows;
}
```

I have access to `$order` which contains the data I want to display but I have no idea how to get it.

Below is a `var_dump` (formatted) of `$order` variable:

```
Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Overrides\Order Object
(
    [refunded_line_items:protected] => 
    [status_transition:protected] => 
    [data:protected] => Array
        (
            [parent_id] => 0
            [status] => on-hold
            [currency] => GBP
            [version] => 4.5.2
            [prices_include_tax] => 
            [date_created] => WC_DateTime Object
                (
                    [utc_offset:protected] => 0
                    [date] => 2020-10-04 18:25:38.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/London
                )

            [date_modified] => WC_DateTime Object
                (
                    [utc_offset:protected] => 0
                    [date] => 2020-10-04 18:25:38.000000
                    [timezone_type] => 3
                    [timezone] => Europe/London
                )

            [discount_total] => 0
            [discount_tax] => 0
            [shipping_total] => 0.00
            [shipping_tax] => 0
            [cart_tax] => 0
            [total] => 2.00
            [total_tax] => 0
            [customer_id] => 1
            [order_key] => wc_order_FeOmJ7jXgWF4R
            [billing] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => Jon
                    [last_name] => Conway
                    [company] => 
                    [address_1] => 
                    [address_2] => 
                    [city] => Frome
                    [state] => 
                    [postcode] => 
                    [country] => 
                    [email] => <**hidden**>
                    [phone] => 
                )

            [shipping] => Array
                (
                    [first_name] => 
                    [last_name] => 
                    [company] => 
                    [address_1] => 
                    [address_2] => 
                    [city] => 
                    [state] => 
                    [postcode] => 
                    [country] => 
                )

            [payment_method] => bacs
            [payment_method_title] => Direct bank transfer
            [transaction_id] => 
            [customer_ip_address] => 127.0.0.1
            [customer_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/605.1.15 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/14.0 Safari/605.1.15
            [created_via] => checkout
            [customer_note] => 
            [date_completed] => 
            [date_paid] => 
            [cart_hash] => cb56eda51b920dc5fbffac1c03fe33b1
        )

    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [line_items] => Array
                (
                    [78] => WC_Order_Item_Product Object
                        (
                            [extra_data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [product_id] => 0
                                    [variation_id] => 0
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [tax_class] => 
                                    [subtotal] => 0
                                    [subtotal_tax] => 0
                                    [total] => 0
                                    [total_tax] => 0
                                    [taxes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [subtotal] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [total] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [order_id] => 1433
                                    [name] => Online concert
                                    [product_id] => 746
                                    [variation_id] => 0
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [tax_class] => 
                                    [subtotal] => 2
                                    [subtotal_tax] => 0
                                    [total] => 2
                                    [total_tax] => 0
                                    [taxes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [total] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [subtotal] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [cache_group:protected] => order-items
                            [meta_type:protected] => order_item
                            [object_type:protected] => order_item
                            [id:protected] => 78
                            [changes:protected] => Array
                                (
                                )

                            [object_read:protected] => 1
                            [default_data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [order_id] => 0
                                    [name] => 
                                    [product_id] => 0
                                    [variation_id] => 0
                                    [quantity] => 1
                                    [tax_class] => 
                                    [subtotal] => 0
                                    [subtotal_tax] => 0
                                    [total] => 0
                                    [total_tax] => 0
                                    [taxes] => Array
                                        (
                                            [subtotal] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                            [total] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                            [data_store:protected] => WC_Data_Store Object
                                (
                                    [instance:WC_Data_Store:private] => WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store Object
                                        (
                                            [internal_meta_keys:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [0] => _order_id
                                                    [1] => _name
                                                    [2] => _product_id
                                                    [3] => _variation_id
                                                    [4] => _quantity
                                                    [5] => _tax_class
                                                    [6] => _subtotal
                                                    [7] => _subtotal_tax
                                                    [8] => _total
                                                    [9] => _total_tax
                                                    [10] => _taxes
                                                    [11] => _product_id
                                                    [12] => _variation_id
                                                    [13] => _qty
                                                    [14] => _tax_class
                                                    [15] => _line_subtotal
                                                    [16] => _line_subtotal_tax
                                                    [17] => _line_total
                                                    [18] => _line_tax
                                                    [19] => _line_tax_data
                                                )

                                            [meta_type:protected] => order_item
                                            [object_id_field_for_meta:protected] => order_item_id
                                            [must_exist_meta_keys:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [stores:WC_Data_Store:private] => Array
                                        (
                                            [coupon] => WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT
                                            [customer] => WC_Customer_Data_Store
                                            [customer-download] => WC_Customer_Download_Data_Store
                                            [customer-download-log] => WC_Customer_Download_Log_Data_Store
                                            [customer-session] => WC_Customer_Data_Store_Session
                                            [order] => WC_Order_Data_Store_CPT
                                            [order-refund] => WC_Order_Refund_Data_Store_CPT
                                            [order-item] => WC_Order_Item_Data_Store
                                            [order-item-coupon] => WC_Order_Item_Coupon_Data_Store
                                            [order-item-fee] => WC_Order_Item_Fee_Data_Store
                                            [order-item-product] => WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store
                                            [order-item-shipping] => WC_Order_Item_Shipping_Data_Store
                                            [order-item-tax] => WC_Order_Item_Tax_Data_Store
                                            [payment-token] => WC_Payment_Token_Data_Store
                                            [product] => MAGE_Product_Data_Store_CPT
                                            [product-grouped] => WC_Product_Grouped_Data_Store_CPT
                                            [product-variable] => WC_Product_Variable_Data_Store_CPT
                                            [product-variation] => WC_Product_Variation_Data_Store_CPT
                                            [shipping-zone] => WC_Shipping_Zone_Data_Store
                                            [webhook] => WC_Webhook_Data_Store
                                            [report-revenue-stats] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Orders\Stats\DataStore
                                            [report-orders] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Orders\DataStore
                                            [report-orders-stats] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Orders\Stats\DataStore
                                            [report-products] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Products\DataStore
                                            [report-variations] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Variations\DataStore
                                            [report-products-stats] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Products\Stats\DataStore
                                            [report-categories] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Categories\DataStore
                                            [report-taxes] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Taxes\DataStore
                                            [report-taxes-stats] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Taxes\Stats\DataStore
                                            [report-coupons] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Coupons\DataStore
                                            [report-coupons-stats] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Coupons\Stats\DataStore
                                            [report-downloads] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Downloads\DataStore
                                            [report-downloads-stats] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Downloads\Stats\DataStore
                                            [admin-note] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\Notes\DataStore
                                            [report-customers] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Customers\DataStore
                                            [report-customers-stats] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Customers\Stats\DataStore
                                            [report-stock-stats] => Automattic\WooCommerce\Admin\API\Reports\Stock\Stats\DataStore
                                        )

                                    [current_class_name:WC_Data_Store:private] => WC_Order_Item_Product_Data_Store
                                    [object_type:WC_Data_Store:private] => order-item-product
                                )

                            [meta_data:protected] => Array
                                (
                                    [0] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                                        (
                                            [current_data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1496
                                                    [key] => Date
                                                    [value] => 2020-10-02 10:00:00
                                                )

                                            [data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1496
                                                    [key] => Date
                                                    [value] => 2020-10-02 10:00:00
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [1] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                                        (
                                            [current_data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1497
                                                    [key] => Adult - £10.00 x 1 = 
                                                    [value] => £10.00
                                                )

                                            [data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1497
                                                    [key] => Adult - £10.00 x 1 = 
                                                    [value] => £10.00
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [2] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                                        (
                                            [current_data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1498
                                                    [key] => Location
                                                    [value] => ,

                                                )

                                            [data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1498
                                                    [key] => Location
                                                    [value] => ,

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [3] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                                        (
                                            [current_data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1499
                                                    [key] => _event_ticket_info
                                                    [value] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ticket_name] => Adult
                                                                    [ticket_price] => 10
                                                                    [ticket_qty] => 1
                                                                    [max_qty] => 
                                                                    [event_date] => 2020-10-02 10:00:00
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1499
                                                    [key] => _event_ticket_info
                                                    [value] => Array
                                                        (
                                                            [0] => Array
                                                                (
                                                                    [ticket_name] => Adult
                                                                    [ticket_price] => 10
                                                                    [ticket_qty] => 1
                                                                    [max_qty] => 
                                                                    [event_date] => 2020-10-02 10:00:00
                                                                )

                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [4] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                                        (
                                            [current_data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1500
                                                    [key] => _event_user_info
                                                    [value] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1500
                                                    [key] => _event_user_info
                                                    [value] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                    [5] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                                        (
                                            [current_data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1501
                                                    [key] => event_id
                                                    [value] => 745
                                                )

                                            [data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1501
                                                    [key] => event_id
                                                    [value] => 745
                                                )

                                        )

                                    [6] => WC_Meta_Data Object
                                        (
                                            [current_data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1503
                                                    [key] => _event_extra_service
                                                    [value] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                            [data:protected] => Array
                                                (
                                                    [id] => 1503
                                                    [key] => _event_extra_service
                                                    [value] => Array
                                                        (
                                                        )

                                                )

                                        )

                                )

                        )

                )

            ... truncated
```

I want to access:

```
[id] => 1499
[key] => _event_ticket_info
[value] => Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ticket_name] => Adult
                [ticket_price] => 10
                [ticket_qty] => 1
                [max_qty] => 
                [event_date] => 2020-10-02 10:00:00
            )
    )
```

To calculate and get the cost from `ticket_price` by `ticket_qty`.

Is this possible? Any idea on how to get this specific order item meta data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get order item custom meta data, first you need to loop through order items, to be able to get that complex custom protected meta data using `WC_Data` method `get_meta()`. Then you will be able to get and calculate your "2nd installment cost as follows:

```php
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'display_email_topay', 10, 2 );
function display_email_topay( $total_rows, $order ) {
    $second_installment_cost = 0; // Initializing

    // Loop through order items
    foreach( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Try to get "_event_ticket_info" item meta value (array)
        $event_ticket_data =  $item->get_meta('_event_ticket_info');

        // Get the data from the array
        if( ! empty($event_ticket_data) ) {
            // extract / Import variables into the current symbol table from an array
            extract($event_ticket_data);
        }

        // if cost and quantity variables exist and have a value more than zero
        if( isset($ticket_price) && $ticket_price > 0 && isset($ticket_qty) && $ticket_qty > 0 ) {
            // Calculating and adding 2nd Installment cost item
            $second_installment_cost += $ticket_price * $ticket_qty;
        }
    }

    if ( $second_installment_cost > 0 ) {
        $total_rows['recurr_not'] = array(
           'label' => __( '2nd Installment', 'woocommerce' ),
           'value'   => wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price($second_installment_cost) )
        );
    }
    return $total_rows;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Related:

- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)
- [Get the metadata of an order item in woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48565643/get-the-metadata-of-an-order-item-in-woocommerce-3/48567687#48567687)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it helped me solve my problem. I had to make one change since  **$event_ticket_data** is a multi dimensional array. I added a second foreach loop to step through the extractions. It all works now.

Comment: @MusicMan62 I have changed a bit my code without an additional foreach… Try it should work as well.

Answer (score 1):

The answer of *LoicTheAztec* helped me solve the problem. This custom meta data array requires a 2nd foreach loop as `$event_ticket_data` is a multi dimensional array.

This is the working code:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_order_item_totals', 'display_email_topay', 10, 2 );
function display_email_topay( $total_rows, $order ) {
 
    $total_ticket=0;
    $total_service=0;
    
        // Loop through order items: get ticket costs
        foreach( $order->get_items() as $ticket ) {
            // Try to get "_event_ticket_info" item meta value (array)
            $event_ticket_data =  $ticket->get_meta('_event_ticket_info'); 
//          echo'<pre>';var_dump($event_ticket_data);echo '</pre><br><br>';
            
            foreach($event_ticket_data as $item) {
                extract($item);
                $total_ticket += $ticket_price * $ticket_qty;
//              echo '<br>'.$ticket_price.' x '.$ticket_qty;
            }
            
            $event_ticket_data =  $ticket->get_meta('_event_extra_service'); 
//          echo'<pre>';var_dump($event_ticket_data);echo '</pre><br><br>';
            
            foreach($event_ticket_data as $item) {
                extract($item);
                $total_service += $service_price * $service_qty;
//              echo '<br>'.$service_price.' x '.$service_qty;
            }           
        }
        
        // work out the cart_total and amount left to pay
        $cart_total = $total_ticket+$total_service;
        $second_installment_cost = $cart_total - $order->get_total();
        
        if ( $second_installment_cost > 0 ) {
            $total_rows['order_total'] = array(
               'label' => __( 'Order Total', 'woocommerce' ),
               'value'   => wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price($cart_total) )
            );
            $total_rows['order_topay'] = array(
               'label' => __( '2nd Installment', 'woocommerce' ),
               'value'   => wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price($second_installment_cost) )
            );
            $total_rows['cart_subtotal'] = array(
               'label' => __( 'To Pay', 'woocommerce' ),
               'value'   => wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price($order->get_total() ) )
            );
        }
        return $total_rows;

}
```