# Get product name at thank you page in woocommerce

Tags: javascript, variables, woocommerce, product

We are doing a WooCommerce Conversion Tracking Custom Integration.

Following this guide (but using custom pixel instead of Facebook's):

https://wedevs.com/docs/woocommerce-conversion-tracking/custom/?utm_source=wporg&utm_medium=Readme&utm_campaign=wcct-lite&utm_content=custom

We would like to pass purchased product's name against our adv_sub5 parameter. Our script looks like this:

```
<script>
(...)
        conversionData: {
            event: '', 
            payout: '', 
            sale: ' { order_total } ', 
            currency: '  { currency }   ',
            adv_sub1: ' { order_subtotal } ',
            adv_sub2: '  { customer_email }   ',
            adv_sub3: '  { order_discount }   ',
            adv_sub4: '  { order_number }   ',
            adv_sub5: '',
        }
    })
</script>
```

We could find the corresponding dynamic variables for all the other parameters, but not for product's name.

We could not find a documentation for the complete list of variables mentioned in the description above.

I wonder if we can just use `{ product_name }` or do something like this:

[Get products names in an array in Woocommerce thankyou page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49273356/get-products-names-in-an-array-in-woocommerce-thankyou-page)

How do we pass this parameter correctly?

Comment: _"I wonder if we can just use { product_name }"_ - that's not on the list of templating tags listed in that plugin's documentation. And the existence of such a single tag would probably not make much sense to begin with, considering that an order can usually contain more than just one product. _"or do something like this"_ - then you would still have to find a way to make those values available "inside" the plugin. Maybe by having the script code read them from a custom data attribute you put one some element in the thank you page, or something like that.