# Get the Product ID from email templates in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In Woocommerce I am trying to find out how to get the **product id** for a completed order inside the Customer completed order email template to store it as a PHP variable. This way I will be able to insert it into an external database.

I already tried `$product->get_id();` but it does not work.

How can get the Product ID in WooCommerce 3+ from email templates?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to loop through Order items… Normally the `WC_Order` object is defined through the variable `$order` mostly defined everywhere in email templates.

So the code to get the product ID will be:

```
// Loop through order items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){

    // Get the product ID
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); 

    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $product = $item->get_product(); 

    // Get product title (name)
    $product_name = $product->get_title(); // or $product->get_name();

    // Get product price
    $product_price = $product->get_price(); 
}
```

See this related thread: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: thanks it worked ! Also if i want to get the product name and price as well what I have to add to the code?

Comment: helpful answer . Thanks

Comment: Could you explain why `$product = $item->get_product();` and then `$product->get_id();`doesn't work? In my case it works for simple products but not for variable products, Im confused here, but `$item->get_product_id();` worked out as expected anyways.

Comment: @svelandiag Sorry but there is No variable products in order items only product variations (from a parent variable product)…