# Get custom order item metadata in Woocommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, metadata, orders

I am using Woocommerce latest version 3.4.2. How can I get some order item metadata and assign them a custom value?

1. I get meta data with a common array `$item_product_data_array`.
2. I need to get a certain value - (Additional modification for the product). And assign custom sku.

Example:
I have coffe - sku 1001, in array - key [0]
Product coffe have additional modification - sugar (meta data)
Need found "Sugar" and assign him custom sku - 50005.

```
[label] => Optionally select [value] => Array ( [0] => Cinnamon [1] => Sugar [2] => Mint )
```

That is, this additive should be in one cycle as a price or quantity. All of them must treat their product with a value [0].

```
    // Get product details
        $items = $order->get_items();

        $sku = array();
        $product_kol = array();
        $product_price = array();
        $item_product_meta_data_array = array();

        foreach( $items as $key => $item){
            $product_kol[] = $item['qty'];
            $product_price[] = $item['line_total'];

            $item_id = $item['product_id'];
            $product = wc_get_product($item_id);
            $sku[] = $product->get_sku();

            $items_meta_data[]  = $item->get_meta_data();          
            $meta_data1 = $item->get_meta('Sugar');
                if( ! empty( $meta_data1 ) ) {
                $skus[] = "50005";
                $item_quantities[] = "1";
            }
        }

        // Product details for sending as one line to an external service
        foreach ($sku as $key => $value){
            $data .= "&product[".$key."]=".$value."";
            $data .= "&product_kol[".$key."]=".$product_kol[$key]."";
            $data .= "&product_price[".$key."]=".$product_price[$key]."";
            if(isset($product_mod[$key])) {
                $data .= "&product_mod[".$key."]=".$product_mod[$key]."";
            }
        }
```

I think this will be useful stuff, since all the modules of additional options to the product add all the values to the meta data. And it is difficult to pull them out and include them in the desired cycle.

So, we should get:

```
//products sku 
$product[0] = "10000";  // Coffe
$product[1] = "10001";  // Juice - second product for axample
$product[2] = "50005";  // Sugar

//products quantity
$product_kol[0] = "1"; // Аmount of coffee
$product_kol[1] = "1"; // Аmount of juice
$product_kol[2] = "1"; // Аmount of sugar

//Modifiers if they exist
$product_mod[2] = "0";  //The product with key 2 is the product modifier with key 0
```

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Latest version. Block "// Product details" works good.

Comment: Thank you! Help, please, with modification of the products and the assignment of the sku. Additional modification for the product always have quantity = 1.

Comment: Guys, could you tell me, what kind of action should be taken? And I'll try to write the code myself. At the moment I do not know where to start.

Comment: If I find the right ingredient in the general cycle -> I give it value '50005' -> I give $item_quantities[] = 1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated:** Your code is really outdated since Woocommerce version 3… See:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

So your code should be:

```
$skus = $item_quantities = $line_item_totals = $items_meta_data = array();

// Loop though order items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item){
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id();
    $product = $item->get_product();

    $item_quantities[] = $item->get_quantity();
    $line_item_totals[] = $item->get_total();
    $skus[]            = $product->get_sku();
    $items_meta_data[]  = $item->get_meta_data();
}

// Product details for sending as one line to an external service
foreach ($skus as $key => $value){
    $data .= "&product[".$key."]=".$value."";
    $data .= "& product_kol[".$key."]=".$item_quantities[$key]."";
    $data .= "& product_price[".$key."]=".$line_item_totals[$key]."";
    if( isset($product_mod[$key]) ) {
        $data .= "&product_mod[".$key."]=".$product_mod[$key]."";
    }
}
```

It should work better… but `$product_mod` is not defined and `$item->get_meta_data()` is not used.

---

Now **To get some custom meta data**, if your custom **meta key** is `Custom thing`, you will use:

```
 $custom_thing = $item->get_meta('Custom thing');
```

This should be included in the foreach loop of order items… Tested and works.

---

Some other things:

- To get the NON discounted order line item total: `$item->get_subtotal();`
- To get the discounted order line item total: `$item->get_total();`
- To get the product price (unit): `$product->get-price();`

Comment: Tell me please, in this case `_custom_thing` - $custom_thing = $product->get_meta( '_Sugar' );? In theory, I need to find all the additives in the meta data and give them my sku. And their quantities will be 1 by default.

Comment: Thank you! The only thing is unfortunately not clear how to achieve the desired task. Maybe I wrote a little unclear what I was trying to achieve... Part `$product_mod`.