# Get some order and order items data in Woocommerce emails

Tags: php, wordpress, templates, woocommerce, orders

I am currently customising the emails that customers receive after a purchase on my website (customer-processing-order, customer-completed-order etc etc). I have copied the email folder from Woocommerce to my child theme.

What I am using a doing is using my own template and then using Woocommerce Classes/API's/Functions to bring in the relevent details of the customers order.

So far I have managed to add in information for:

- Customer Name
- Customer Order No
- Order Date
- Shipping/Billing Address
- Product Item Name
- Product Item Quantity

I have done this mostly by using the variable function/class  $order (I.E id; ?>, billing_first_name; ?>)

My problem is I am having no success in trying to get the product / item (individual) price to show. I have looked and searched for all the ways to do this but EVERYTHING I have tried has so far failed.

I am also having trouble with printing the Sub Total, Shipping, Payment Method and the Total (Overall Cost). Maybe I am going about it in the wrong way?

These are links I have used to try and guide me

[How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details#)

https://businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/

Any help would be fantastic. Here is my Code ...

```
<?php           
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_data) { 
    $product = $item_data->get_product();

    //PRODUCT NAME
    $product_name = $product->get_name(); 
    echo $product_name// THIS WORKS AND PRINTS CORRECTLY
    //PRODUCT QUANTITY
    $get_quantity = WC_Order_Item::get_quantity();  
    echo $get_quantity // THIS WORKS AND PRINTS CORRECTLY

    //PRODUCT PRICE
    $get_price = new WC_Order_Item_Fee::get_amount( $context );
    echo $get_price // THIS DOES NOT WORK

    // TRYING BELOW ALSO DOES NOT WORK ...

    $getproduct = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
    $price = $getproduct->get_price();  

    //HOW WOULD I GET :
    /** SUBTOTAL , SHIPPING , PAYMENT METHOD AND TOTAL **/  

?>
```

Comment: Lovely Jubbly, Thanks for the comments. Extremely Helpful and I'm very grateful!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are some errors in your code…

**1) For the order items data:**

```
// Loop though order line items      
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) { 

    // PRODUCT NAME
    $product_name = $item->get_name(); 
    echo $product_name

    // PRODUCT QUANTITY
    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();  
    echo $quantity;

    // Get the WC_Product Object instance
    $product = $item->get_product();

    // PRODUCT PRICE
    $product_price = $product->get_price();
    echo $product_price;

    // LINE ITEM SUBTOTAL (Non discounted)
    $item_subtotal = $item->get_subtotal();
    echo $item_subtotal;

    // LINE ITEM SUBTOTAL TAX (Non discounted)
    $item_subtotal_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax();
    echo $item_subtotal_tax;

    // LINE ITEM TOTAL (discounted)
    $item_total = $item->get_total();
    echo $item_total;

    // LINE ITEM TOTAL TAX (discounted)
    $item_total_tax = $item->get_total_tax();
    echo $item_total_tax;

endforeach;
```

See for reference: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

---

**2) For the Order data:**

```
// PAYMENT METHOD:
$payment_method = $order->get_payment_method(); // The payment method slug
$payment_method_title = $order->get_payment_method(); // The payment method title

// SHIPPING METHOD:
$shipping_method = $order->get_shipping_method(); // The shipping method slug

// SHIPPING TOTALS:
$shipping_total     = $order->get_shipping_total(); // The shipping total
$shipping_total_tax = $order->get_shipping_tax(); // The shipping total tax

// DISCOUNT TOTAL
$shipping_total     = $order->get_total_discount(); // The discount total

// ORDER TOTALS
$total     = $order->get_total(); // The order total
$total_tax = $order->get_total_tax(); // The order tax total
```