# How to get orders of a user in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress Version 5.3.2
Woocommerce Version 3.8.1

**To acheive** Show user his **purchased orders** along with **order_items** (products in the order)

**What I have tried**

Saw [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details) , [Get some order and order items data in Woocommerce emails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51748956/get-some-order-and-order-items-data-in-woocommerce-emails) ,https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query

Still couldn't solve my issue.

**Error I am facing**

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_id() on
>   array

**Code**

```
//got the user
$user = wp_get_current_user();
//In my case $user->ID returns 1

$args = array(
    'customer_id' => $user->ID,
    'status' => 'confirmed',
);
//Since i only want the confirmed orders
$order= wc_get_orders( $args );
$order_id  = $order->get_id();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can see from the [docs](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/function-wc_get_orders.html), `wc_get_orders` returns an `array` or `stdClass`. The error message tells you that you cannot call `get_id` of an `array`, so you have an `array`. Because the customer you are searching with has multiple confirmed orders. Solution:

```
//...
$orders = wc_get_orders( $args );
if (!is_array($orders)) $orders = [$orders];
//...
```

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling a bit more after the accepted solution.
Initially i was getting a complete array of orders, After iterating through that array i found what i was looking for.

```
    $user = wp_get_current_user();
    $args = array(
    //'customer_id' => $user->ID
    'customer_id' => 6
);
    $orders = wc_get_orders($args);
    foreach($orders as $order){
        $order_id  = $order->get_id();        
        echo $order_id . "<br/>";
    }
```

This foreach allowed accessing the order_id i required.