# How to query Woocommerce orders on a page

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, orders

I want to create a page that displays a query from the database to show some order details.

How to display this query on a page?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is multiple ways to get Woocommerce Orders:

1) Woocommerce has a dedicated function [`wc_get_orders()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/wiki/wc_get_orders-and-WC_Order_Query) that will give you an array of WC_Order objects:

```
$orders = wc_get_orders( array('numberposts' => -1) );

// Loop through each WC_Order object
foreach( $orders as $order ){
    echo $order->get_id() . '<br>'; // The order ID
    echo $order->get_status() . '<br>'; // The order status
}
```

To get the order data see the links below

---

2) You can also use a Wordpress [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query):

```
$loop = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'         => 'shop_order',
    'post_status'       =>  array_keys( wc_get_order_statuses() ),
    'posts_per_page'    => -1,
) );

// The Wordpress post loop
if ( $loop->have_posts() ): 
while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();

// The order ID
$order_id = $loop->post->ID;

// Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
$order = wc_get_order($loop->post->ID);

endwhile;

wp_reset_postdata();

endif;
```

To get the order data see the links below

---

3) You can use a SQL query

```
global $wpdb;
$results = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}posts WHERE post_type LIKE 'shop_order'");

// Loop through each order post object
foreach( $results as $result ){
    $order_id = $result->ID; // The Order ID

    // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
    $order    = wc_get_order( $result->ID );
}
```

---

You will be able to get all order details from the [`WC_Order` object](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order.html) as explained in:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

---

**Displaying the data as a list in a table**

To display the orders in a list, you should have a look to the woocommerce deprecated template [myaccount/my-orders.php](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.4/templates/myaccount/my-orders.php) or to [myaccount/orders.php template](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/release/3.4/templates/myaccount/orders.php)…

It will give you a model…

Comment: oh great... thank you! I like the 3rd option, as i have a custom query I want to use.  I assume I would just replace your sql query "SELECT * FROM {$wpdb->prefix}p..." with the one I want to use?

Comment: okay awesome.. and where do I actually put the whole piece of code you've provided? Does it go into functions.php? How do I actually make it display?

Comment: @Michelle You can embed that in a custom shortcode function that you will put in your function.php… Then you will be able to use it everywhere to get a display. See [some examples of shortcodes functions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user%3A3730754+shortcode+)

Comment: cool.. thanks! Is there an easier way to add it? shortcodes are a little above my experience level!

Comment: Done! I've also started a new question with my "Code" - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950316/woocommerce-shortcode-for-custom-query-not-working Thanks!

Comment: @Michelle Answered your new question, tested and working…

Answer (score 0):

As long as it's the last query executed, you can use `$wpdb->last_query` to grab the last query. You'll need to have `define('SAVEQUERIES', true)` in your `wp-config.php` for this

Comment: OP is not talking about the "last query" but how to run a query and display the results...

Comment: Sorry... what I mean is.. i want to create a page the supplier can log into, that has all new orders listed, live.  So i'm looking for the code I'd use to display the query on a page. Thanks!