# Get orders from a SQL query displayed on as a list in Woocommerce

Tags: php, sql, woocommerce, shortcode, orders

In woocommerce, I'm trying to create a shortcode to put in my `function.php` document, that displays a custom database query on a page.
There's something wrong with it though and i'm not sure what.

```
function sqlquery_shortcode($atts) {
    global $wpdb;
    $results = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT a.order_id, a.order_item_id, a.order_item_name, b.meta_key, b.meta_value
        FROM 7pW9iX3L_woocommerce_order_items a
        JOIN 7pW9iX3L_woocommerce_order_itemmeta  b 
            ON a.order_item_id = b.order_item_id
        JOIN 7pW9iX3L_posts c               
            ON a.order_id = c.ID
        JOIN 7pW9iX3L_postmeta d
            ON c.ID = d.post_id
        WHERE order_item_type = 'line_item'
    ");

    // Loop through each order post object
    foreach($results as $result) {
        $order_id = $result->ID; // The Order ID

        // Get an instance of the WC_Order Object
        $order = wc_get_order( $result->ID );
    }
}
add_shortcode("sqlquery_shortcode");
```

Comment: first you are not returning anything in your function just getting result from your query and looping  through the result so what exactly you want here? what error you are facing?

Comment: i'm trying to display the output of the SQL query thats inside the code, on a page... but I'm very, very new at this! I just want to create a page on my website that displays live orders as they come in for the supplier to see

Comment: okay so are you sure that your query returning  any result?

Comment: Yes it should be

Comment: Could you please help me write the query to make it display the data, then to make it into a shortcode so I can add it to my page? I'd appreciate it!! Thank you

Comment: no problem i will assume your query is working so what data you want to display in the page?

Comment: I want to display the order Id, product description, product attribute, customer name, customer address, delivery date and the message. I haven't finished writing the query yet but these will be the fields i'll output.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is many little errors and mistakes. Your SQL query was incorrect, so I have changed in a way to make it work first.

Here is your revisited code to get order line items from your SQL query in an html table. It's just a functional and tested **example** code, that you should need to change for your needs:

```
add_shortcode('sqlquery_shortcode', 'sqlquery_shortcode');
function sqlquery_shortcode( $atts ) {
    global $wpdb;

    $results = $wpdb->get_results("
        SELECT a.order_id, a.order_item_id AS item_id, a.order_item_name AS item_name,
        b.meta_value AS product_id, c.meta_value AS quantity, d.meta_value AS subtotal
        FROM {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_items a
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta  b ON a.order_item_id = b.order_item_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta  c ON a.order_item_id = c.order_item_id
        JOIN {$wpdb->prefix}woocommerce_order_itemmeta  d ON a.order_item_id = d.order_item_id
        WHERE a.order_item_type = 'line_item'
        AND b.meta_key = '_product_id'
        AND c.meta_key = '_qty'
        AND d.meta_key = '_line_subtotal'
        ORDER BY a.order_id DESC
    ");

    // Start buffering
    ob_start();

    echo '<table><tr>';
    echo '<th>Order ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Item ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Product ID</th>';
    echo '<th>Item Name</th>';
    echo '<th>Quantity</th>';
    echo '<th>Subtotal</th>';
    echo '</tr>';
    // Loop through each order post object
    foreach( $results as $result ){

        // Html display
        echo '<tr>';
        echo '<td>' . $result->order_id . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $result->item_id . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $result->product_id . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $result->item_name . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $result->quantity . '</td>';
        echo '<td>' . $result->subtotal . '</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

    echo '</table>';

    // Return output (render the buffered data)
    return ob_get_clean();
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

---

**USAGE:**

You will paste that shortcode `[sqlquery_shortcode]` in the Wordpress text editor of a page or a post.

Or you can also paste the following in any php template or file:

```
echo do_shortcode( "[sqlquery_shortcode]" );
```

or in between html tags:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( "[sqlquery_shortcode]" ); ?>
```

You will get something like:

[image]

Comment: @Michelle Don't exaggerate :) Thanks … I am just helping you and pushing you to find the way… So like this you try and learn.

Comment: @Michelle For styling your table you should look at: [Top 25 Simple, Yet Beautiful CSS3 Table Templates And Examples 2018](https://colorlib.com/wp/css3-table-templates/) … anyway in your new question, there is like too many columns in your table to make it responsive, as it will mostly always displayed on responsive mode (which is not really readable in my opinion).

Comment: thanks I'll check out that link.. This particular page doesn't need to be responsive.. it's just a page for suppliers to view the orders.