# Google analytics integration for a custom Order received page in Woocommerce 3

Tags: javascript, php, woocommerce, google-analytics, orders

I have a custom thank you page for after checkout is finished in WooCommerce where I need to insert order data into a Google ecommerce tracking tag to record the sale in analytics. One part of that is adding the following for each item in the order...

```
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
  'id': <?php echo $order_id?>,    // Transaction ID. Required.
  'name': 'ACME Product',          // Product name. Required.
  'sku': '1234',                   // SKU/code.
  'category': 'Product Category',  // Category or variation.
  'price': '10.00',                // Unit price.
  'quantity': '1'                  // Quantity.
});
```

but with inserting the order item's real data using PHP, not the placeholders you see there for name, sku, category, price, and quantity.

In Googling around for answers, I see that I must now use
`wc_display_item_meta ( $item );` rather than the deprecated `$item_meta    = new WC_Order_Item_Meta( $item['item_meta'], $_product );`

What I need help with, because I don't yet fully know PHP and I can't seem to find any close examples, is how do I begin to grab the values? Is it a foreach of some kind, or is there a way to directly parse out each item's individual properties out of the order item into a variable that I can then insert in these placeholders?

Comment: You need to iterate through order items using a foreach loop… And what about if you have 2 or more items in the customer order? How do you think to manage each item? Your actual code seems to manage just one item and you should better use existing integrated plugins…

Comment: I do know I need to use a loop to do this same output for multiple items, hence the question. I would love to use a plugin for this. But there isn't one for a custom thankyou page in WooCommerce. Not that I can find. Do you know of one?

Comment: I have tried to answer… The php code works without mistakes and errors… Now you may have o make some little changes, testing that for real. But this answer your question title.

Comment: @rw-intechra, please look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54130384/google-analytics-integration-for-orders-without-online-payment-transaction-in-wo). Maybe you will see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following *(you may have to make some changes and add the affiliation Id)*:

```
?>
<script>
ga('require', 'ecommerce');
<?php

// GET the WC_Order object instance from, the Order ID
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$order_key = $order->get_order_key();

$transaction_id = $order->get_transaction_id(); // Doesn't always exist

$transaction_id = $order_id; // (Or the order key or the transaction ID if it exist)

?>
ga('ecommerce:addTransaction', {
    'id':        '<?php echo $transaction_id; // To be checked ?>',
    'affiliation': '<?php echo 'UA-XXXXX-Y'; // replace by yours ?>',
    'revenue':   '<?php echo $order->get_total(); ?>',
    'shipping':      '<?php echo $order->get_shipping_total(); ?>',
    'tax':       '<?php echo $order->get_total_tax(); ?>',
    'currency':      '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); // Optional ?>' 
}); <?php

// LOOP START: Iterate through order items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) :
    // Get an instance of the WC_Product object
    $product = $item->get_product();

    // Get the product categories for the product
    $categories = wp_get_post_terms( $item->get_product_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $category = reset($categories); // Keep only the first product category
?>
ga('ecommerce:addItem', {
    'id':     '<?php echo $transaction_id; ?>',
    'name':       '<?php echo $item->get_name(); ?>',
    'sku':    '<?php echo $product->get_sku(); ?>',
    'category': '<?php echo $category; ?>',
    'price':      '<?php echo wc_get_price_excluding_tax($product);  // OR wc_get_price_including_tax($product) ?>',
    'quantity': '<?php echo $item->get_quantity(); ?>',
    'currency': '<?php echo get_woocommerce_currency(); // Optional ?>' 
});
<?php
endforeach; // LOOP END
?>
ga('ecommerce:send');
</script>
<?php
```

This code is partially tested and doesn't throw errors… But it need to be tested for real. I hope it will work.

Related:

- [Google Analytics related documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/ecommerce) *(made from this documentation)*
- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Loic, tell me please where should this code be located?

Comment: @АлександраКузнецова This code can be included in `Woocommerce_thankyou` hook I think…

Comment: Thank you. I'm eager to give this a try. I'll have to wait a few days to merge it into another developer's branch for testing, but on the surface it looks like it will work! I'll be sure to come back and mark it as the accepted answer when I get it working.

Comment: Just an update to say thank you very much for this code. It worked perfectly the first time. I've marked it as the solution.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec, Thank you!;)