# Get and use the product type in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I'm working on a project and I'm stuck in getting Woocommerce product types as 'simple', 'variable', 'grouped' or 'external'...

**What I want to achieve:** 
On the Thank you page, where it says "*Thank you. Your order has been received.*".  
I want to show a particular text there if product is 'simple' and another text is product is variable or grouped or external, so something like:

```
if (product->get_type() == 'simple') {// (for simple product)
      //show a text
}else {// (for variable, grouped and external product) 
      //show another text
}
```

I have been able to use this:

```
function custome_tank_you_text($order_id) {
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    foreach ( $items as $item ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );

        $product->get_type();
    }

    if( $product == 'simple'){ ?>
        <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you for topping up your wallet. It has been updated!', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>
    <?php
    } else {?>
    <p class="woocommerce-notice woocommerce-notice--success woocommerce-thankyou-order-received"><?php echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received!', 'woocommerce' ), $order ); ?></p>
    <?php
    }
}
add_shortcode('thank-u-msg', 'custome_tank_you_text');
```

But this will only echo the Else statement.

Is there something I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Thank you very much for your answer... mere looking at it, i'm sure it would work (which i am really glad about)... The main reason why i posted this question is to find a way to actually get product type so that i can use `if ( $product->is_type('simple') ) { Do this } ` I want to use this across the website, not just the thank you page. is there a way i could write this without using add_filter or add_action (it can be add_shortcode(), i.e. i can embed the code in a shortcode and use it wherever i want ). Thanks so much

Answer (score 18, accepted):

**Updated:**

For the product type, you can use the following [`WC_Product` methods](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html):

- To get the product type you will use `get_type()` method
- To **check** the product type inside an IF statement you will use `is_type()` method

See at the end of this answer how to get the `WC_Product` object instance.

Now since WooCommerce 3 your code is a bit outdated and with some errors… Also remember that an order can have many items, so it's needed to break the loop (keeping the first item). You can use directly the dedicated filter hook `woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text` this way:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_thankyou_order_received_text', 'custom_thankyou_order_received_text', 20, 2 );
function custom_thankyou_order_received_text( $thankyou_text, $order ){
    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
        // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object from the WC_Order_Item_Product
        $product = $item->get_product();

        if( $product->is_type('simple') ){
            $thankyou_text = __( 'Thank you for topping up your wallet. It has been updated!', 'woocommerce' );
        } else {
            $thankyou_text = __( 'Thank you. Your order has been received!', 'woocommerce' );
        }
        break; // We stop the loop and keep the first item
    }
    return $thankyou_text;
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). tested and works.

> [image: $order]

Related: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

---

**ADDITION - How to get the `WC_Product` object** *(to use* [`is_type()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_is_type) *or* [`get_type()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Product.html#_get_type) *methods)*

> Sometimes you can't get the product type globally… as it depends on the `WC_Product` object.

> 1. **From a dynamic product id** variable (when you doesn't have the $product object:

> ```
> $product = wc_get_product( $product_id );
> ```

> or

> ```
> $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
> ```

> 2. **From `$product` global variable** on single product pages *(and on product archive pages inside the loop)*:

> ```
> global $product;
> ```

> ```
> // Check that WC_Product instance $product variable is defined and accessible
> ```

```
if ( ! is_a( $product, 'WC_Product' ) ) {
    $product = wc_get_product( get_the_id() );
```

> 3. **In cart items:**

> ```
> // Loop throught cart items
> ```

```
foreach( WC()->cart->get_cart() as $cart_item ){
    $product = $cart_item['data'];
}
```

> 3. **In order items:**

> ```
> // Loop through order items
> ```

```
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product();
}
```

Comment: Work perfectly. I just need to figure out how to get product type globally, so that i can use it in any template for any page. Is it visible? because i am trying to do same thing for the Order Again template (Show Topup Again for simple product and Order again for other product types but i kept on getting "Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_items() on string" on line `foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {`

Comment: @KolawoleEmmanuelIzzy I have added an addition at the end of my answer.

Comment: i have gone through the updated content and the reference link, i noticed that in the reference link, an order ID is specified but in my case i order ID is not specified as i want this to affect all Order IDs. I have tried to use the updated content on the order-again woocommerce template but still got `Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_items() on null in` . I'm sorry if i'm stressing you