# Display value from ACF field in Woocommerce order email

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields, email-notifications

I´m trying to display a value for delivery date in the emails that Woocommerce automatic sends to the customer when the order is being processed.

I have created a Advanced custom field value called 'leveranstid' and I want it to be shown with every product in the email. I´ve tried to add the code below to the functions.php but it doesn´t seem to work. Nothing shows. I would be very grateful if someone please help me find what´s wrong?

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 
'ts_order_item_meta_start', 10, 4 );
function ts_order_item_meta_start( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text 
) {

$leverans = get_field(’leveranstid’, $post_id);
echo $leverans;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable `$post_id` is not defined in `$leverans = get_field('leveranstid', $post_id);`. Instead try:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_start', 'display', 10, 4 );
function ts_order_item_meta_start( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {

    if( $leverans = get_field( 'leveranstid', $item->get_product_id() ) ;
        echo $leverans;
}
```

It should work if `'leveranstid'` ACF field is defined for your products.

For reference see: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Thanks but I still doesn´t see the value in the order email. And, yes, the term 'leveranstid' is defined in my products.