# wordpress AFC getting the value of a dustom field

Tags: php, wordpress

Im trying to show the value of a product field created with AFC
I can see the full product object and the value is displayed correctly.
Foolowing the doc I should use

```
$value = get_field( "geolocation" );
```

or

```
$value = get_fields( "geolocation" );
```

But value is always empty
I have also tried to pass the product id and the item id like

```
$value = get_field( "geolocation", $item->get_id() );
```

I have printed the full object, below is the relevant part

```
{ 
     "id":176,
     "key":"geolocation",
     "value":{ 
         "address":"Test address",
         "lat":"20.5271494",
         "lng":"-1.6597097999999733"
      }
 }
```

What im trying to print is the address, lat and lng

Comment: What's the field type ? textbox ? or other types ...

Comment: the field type is text

Comment: You created a field (geolocation) and that has three values (address, lat, lng) ? How it's possible ? because as you said that's a text filed ? anyway, try once with `echo $value->address;` and check output

Comment: actually I cant not answer that question coz I didnt make the fields. I know that I need to call those values because I printed the full object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was calling the method wrong. First I needed to look into the products object

```
$geolocation = get_field('geolocation',$item->get_product_id());
```

Since in my case geolocation is an array I just needed to go through

```
$address = $geolocation['address'];
$lat = $geolocation['lat'];
$lng = $geolocation['lng'];
```

This question helped a lot
[Display product ACF value in Woocommerce admin email notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52952865/display-product-acf-value-in-woocommerce-admin-email-notifications)