# How to get order items on a foreach loop in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, wordpress, methods, woocommerce, orders

When I try to get my order items for an order via my `functions.php` I'm getting this issue here:

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method WC_Order::get_order_items()

This is my code (I can't find the problem):

```
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu_objects', 'set_navigation_user_name' );
function set_navigation_user_name( $menu_items ) {

    //Get current user
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    foreach ( $menu_items as $menu_item ) {
        if ( '{user_name}' === $menu_item->title ) {
            //Get first and lastname from current user
            $user_firstname = $current_user->user_firstname;
            $user_lastname  = $current_user->user_lastname;

            $menu_item->title = $user_firstname . ' ' . $user_lastname;
        } elseif ( '{available_pay}' === $menu_item->title ) {

            $available_pay = 0;

            $order_states = array(
                'wc-completed',
                'wc-pending'
            );

            $orders = wc_get_orders( array(
                'numberposts' => - 1,
                'meta_key'    => '_customer_user',
                'meta_value'  => get_current_user_id(),
                'post_status' => $order_states
            ) );

            foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
                if ( count( $order->get_order_items() ) > 0 ) {
                    foreach ( $order->get_order_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                        //Order pay
                        $order_pay = wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', true );

                        //Add order pay to available pay
                        $available_pay += $order_pay;
                    }
                }
            }

            $menu_item->title = 'Order pay sum: ' . wc_price( $available_pay );
        }
    }

    return $menu_items;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use instead the [`WC_Order` method `get_items()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Abstract_Order.html#691-712)… 
as `WC_Order` `get_order_items()` method doesn't exist for Woocommerce…

Also since Woocommerce 3 you can use [`WC_Order_Item_Product` `get_total()`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_get_total) method instead of `wc_get_order_item_meta( $item_id, '_line_total', true );`

So inside your code you will change the following:

```
            foreach ( $orders as $order ) {
                if ( count( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) {
                    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
                        // Add order pay to available pay
                        $available_pay += $item->get_total();
                    }
                }
            }
```

Related threads:

- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)
- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344?r=SearchResults&s=2|61.7257#44708344)

Comment: This works. Thank you! The other method works fine for example on the order page, strange.