# How to grab item data from WooCommerce order

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

I need to take data from order of customer

Need to take item ID and quantity.

Tried with but not working

```
$item_data = $item_values->get_data();
foreach ($item_data as $item) {
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $quantity = $item['quantity'];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a **`foreach`** loop with order items from a dynamic Order ID **`$order_id`** *(or from  the `WC_Order` object* **`$order`**):

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object (if you don't have the WC_Order object yet)
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// Loop through order items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) { 
    // Get an instance of the WC_Product Object
    $product = $item->get_product();

    // Get the product ID
    $product_id = $product->get_id();

    // Get the item quantity
    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();
}
```

References:

- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)
- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)