# Custom post type data and order item data in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, orders

I am using a plugin, [WooCommerce Custom Post Type Manager](https://reigelgallarde.me/doc/woocommerce-custom-post-type-manager/), along with WooCommerce that enables the use of custom post types as products. This is working pretty well for the most part, but I want to be able to control inventory and I am able to see the problem. In the database under the order_item_meta table, the product_id = 0. Because the product_id is empty, there is no way to update the stock on a completed purchase.

I know that WooCommerce made some changes to where it searched if a post_type was a  'product' and if not, certain things failed. I am wondering if there is a filter hook or another way to add the product id with a custom function at checkout?

This is the function I am trying to create to control a custom type of inventory, we are selling event "seats". And no, even the regular "stock" does not work, probably because of the same reason.

```
function update_course_seats( $order_id ){
  $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
  $items = $order->get_items();
  foreach ( $items as $item ) {
    $product_id = $item->get_product_id(); // this returns 0
    if($product_id != 0) {
      wc_update_order_item_meta( $item, '_seats', 10 ); // example number
    }
  }

//add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'update_course_seats');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you should  use `woocommerce_add_cart_item_data` action hook, to store your Custom Post Type (CTP) **Id** on add to cart…  But for that you will need to display, on your CTP pages, inside the add to cart form, a hidden field with the CTP Id like:

```
<input type="hidden" name="ctpost_id" value="<?php echo get_the_id(); ?>">
```

Now you can add this hooked function, that will add as custom cart item data your CTP Id:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'add_custom_cart_item_data', 10, 3 );
function add_custom_cart_item_data( $cart_item_data, $product_id, $variation_id ){
    if( isset( $_POST['ctpost_id'] ) ) {
        $cart_item_data['ctpost_id'] = wc_clean( $_POST['ctpost_id'] );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}
```

---

The Second hook to be used is `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook, to add custom order item meta data *(or to make changes to order item data)*. This hook is triggered before payment gateways process during order creation.

You can use `WC_data` `add_meta_data()` method to save your CTP Id as a custom CTP ID like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'save_cpt_id_to_order_item_data', 10, 4 );
function save_cpt_id_to_order_item_data( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $order ){
    if( isset($cart_item['ctpost_id']) && $cart_item['ctpost_id'] > 0 ) {
        // Add the custom CTP post ID
        $item->add_meta_data('_ctpost_id', $cart_item['ctpost_id'] );
    }

    // And here for example you add seats as custom cart item data 
    if( isset($cart_item['quantity']) ) {
        $item->add_meta_data( 'Seats', $cart_item['quantity'], true );
    }
}
```

When the **order will get paid**, you will **be able to update everything required**, as you will have **your CTP post ID** as custom order item data.

---

Then finally, you can use `woocommerce_payment_complete` as follow:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_payment_complete', 'action_payment_complete_callback', 10, 1 );
function action_payment_complete_callback( $order_id ){
    $order = wc_get_order();

    // Loop through order items
    foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
        $ctp_id = $item->get_meta('_ctpost_id'); // Get the CTP post ID

        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

Or `woocommerce_order_status_changed` hooks like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_status_changed', 'action_order_status_changed_callback', 10, 4 );
function action_order_status_changed_callback( $order_id, $status_from, $status_to, $order ){
    if( in_array( $status_to, ['processing','completed'] ) ) {
        // Loop through order items
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
            $ctp_id = $item->get_meta('_ctpost_id'); // Get the CTP post ID

            // Your code goes here
        }
    }
}
```

Related: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318?r=SearchResults&s=1|87.2961#45706318).

Comment: This looks promising! I will try it right away. As to the product id, where you have $values['custom_id'] what method do I use to get that from the post id? I assume that $values will contain that info?