# How to update WooCommerce order item quantity

Tags: php, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders, product-quantity

I need to **update the order item meta in a woocommerce** oder on checkout page or while woocommerce creates the order.
I'm using the plugin **visual product configurator** and it is not passing the right quantity of some items of the order to woocommerce order meta, especially when I use multiple variations on the same product.

Is there a **hook** for me to use to update the item quantity for a certain order item and how can I use it?
The plugin returns me an array with all the cart information and I can only check if an item of the order appears multiple times - if yes I need to change the quantity of that item to that number in the woocommerce order/database.

I was thinking of adding the following hook to my functions.php

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'change_qty', 1,1);


function change_qty($item_qty){

  foreach($item_qty as $qty) {
    $qty['product_id'] = $id;
    $qty['qty'] = $new_qty
    $order->update_meta_data('quantity', $new_qty, $id)
  }
}
```

Whereas $item_qty is be an multi-dimensional array containing the item_ids and adjusted quantities.

Another problem I'm facing is that I dont know when I need to call that function because I get the array from the plugin on the checkout page, but I think WooCommerce has not yet created an order at that moment?

The result should be an adjusted item quantity in the woocommerce order summary in the backend.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To update the order item quantity, you can use `WC_Order_Item_Product` [`set_quantity()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html#_set_quantity).

The correct hook to update order items (line items) is [`woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#386), that is triggered during order creation, before data is saved to databased.

```
add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item', 'change_order_line_item_quantity', 10, 4 );
function change_order_line_item_quantity( $item, $cart_item_key, $cart_item, $order ) {
    // Your code goes below

    // Get order item quantity
    $quantity = $item->get_quantity();

    $new_qty = $quantity + 2;

    // Update order item quantity
    $item->set_quantity( $new_qty );
}
```

The function arguments (variables) are defined and usable:

- `$item` is the `WC_Order_Item_Product` Object (not saved yet to database)
- `$cart_item_key` is the related cart item key
- `$cart_item` is the related cart item data
- `$order` is the WC_Order Object (not saved yet to database)

**Related:**

- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in Woocommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)
- [WC_Order_Item_Product Class and methods API Documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Order_Item_Product.html)
- [`WC_Checkout` and `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook located in the `create_order_line_items()` method](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WC_Checkout.html#347-391)

Comment: Thank you, I'm not quite understanding all variables in the function cahnge_order_line_item_quantity though, where do I have to declare them or are they already declared when I create an order?

Comment: Function arguments (following variables) as  `$item`, `$cart_item_key`, `$cart_item` and `$order` are defined and usable.

Comment: Okay, I just tested it, it works. Do you have any reference or documentation where I can read about those Variables? I want to check if a product_id is the same as the one which is looping through in the function? I $item referring to the SKU, ProductID or something else?

Comment: @erik7 I have added some links and explanation

Comment: Thank you, I'm checking

Answer (score -2):

This can help you (we hook into payment completed notification from the payment provider). If you want to update the `_qty` just after the order was created, I can change my function. But for now I would update it only when the payment was successful.:

```
/**
 * Update order item qty after payment successful
 */
add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_complete_order_status', 'update_order_item_qty', 10, 2 );
function update_order_item_qty( $order_status, $order_id ) {

    //Get the order and items
    $order = new WC_Order( $order_id );
    $items = $order->get_items();

    //New qty
    $new_qty = 0;

    foreach ( $items as $item_id => $item_data ) {
        update_meta_data( '_qty', $new_qty, $item_id );
    }
}
```

Please try if this is what you'r looking for.

Comment: This doesnt work because I dont have the order id afterwards - I have the quantity information only during the checkout process, so I have to somehow change it during this process

Comment: You have it afterwards. Every order get's through the payment completed status and at the point you know the order id. Or do you want to change the qty during the payment so that the customer get's more items than he see in the cart (maybe with a higher pricing)?

Comment: No its just for backend purposes so that we see the correct item quantity in the backend