# Get an array of specific data from order items in WooCommerce 3

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce, jagged-arrays

I need the following response in a json:

```php
    $output = array(
        'storeCode' => '123456',
        'firstName' => $fname,
        'lastName' => $lname,
        'dateOfBirth' => '1983-04-01',
        'mobilePhone' => $mobile,
        'email' => $email,
        'address' => array(
        'street' => $address1,
        'suiteApartment' => $address2,
        'city' => $city,
        'state' => $state,
        'zipCode'=> $zip
        ), 
        'products' => $orderitems,
        'redirectUrl' => $cburl,
        'referenceNumber' => $order_id
    );
```

I can only get the first instance of `$orderitems` when I try the following:

```
    $order = wc_get_order($order_id);

    // Get the order ID
    $order_id = $order->get_id();

    // Initialising
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $count = 0;

    // Loop through Order items
    foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ):
        $product      = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object

        $product_id   = $item->get_product_id(); // the Product id
        $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id(); // the Variation id

        $item_type    = $item->get_type(); // Type of the order item ("line_item")

        $item_name    = $item->get_name(); // Name of the product
        $quantity     = $item->get_quantity();  
        $tax_class    = $item->get_tax_class();
        $line_subtotal     = $item->get_subtotal(); // Line subtotal (non discounted)
        $line_subtotal_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Line subtotal tax (non discounted)
        $line_total        = $item->get_total(); // Line total (discounted)
        $line_total_tax    = $item->get_total_tax(); // Line total tax (discounted)

        $orderitems = array(
            'id' => $product_id,
            'description' => $item_name,
            'quantity' => $quantity,
            'value' => $line_subtotal,
            'salesTax' => $line_subtotal_tax
        );
        $count++; 
    endforeach;
```

Why am I only getting the first item in the array when echo out the variable?

Answer (score 0):

There is some little mistakes in your code… Try the following where you will get the specific data for all order items in your variable to be used on your `'products'` argument:

```
$order_items = $order->get_items(); // Get order items array of objects
$items_count = count($items); // Get order items count
$items_data  = []; // Initializing

// Loop through order items
foreach ( $order_items as $item_id => $item ) {
    $variation_id = item->get_variation_id();
    $product_id   = $variation_id > 0 ? $variation_id : $item->get_product_id();

    // Set specific data for each item in the array
    $items_data[] = array(
        'id'          => $product_id,
        'description' => $item->get_name(),
        'quantity'    => $item->get_quantity(),
        'value'       => $item->get_subtotal(),
        'salesTax'    => $item->get_subtotal_tax(),
    );
}
```

Then this will be used in:

```
$output = array(
    'storeCode'       => '123456',
    'firstName'       => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
    'lastName'        => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
    'dateOfBirth'     => '1983-04-01',
    'mobilePhone'     => $order->get_billing_phone(),
    'email'           => $order->get_billing_email(),
    'address'         => array(
        'street'          => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
        'suiteApartment'  => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
        'city'            => $order->get_billing_city(),
        'state'           => $order->get_billing_state(),
        'zipCode'         => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
    ),
    'products'        => $items_data, // <=== HERE
    'redirectUrl'     => $cburl,
    'referenceNumber' => $order->get_id(),
);
```

It should work as expected.

**Related:**

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)