# WooCommerce Add-ons information in Google Sheets

Tags: javascript, php, google-apps-script, google-sheets, woocommerce

I am exporting WooCommerce orders to a google sheets using WooCommerce Webhooks and Apps Script

I have two queires

1) How do I reference WooCommerce "add-ons" data

2) Parent order ID is not showing in google sheet

```js
function doPost(e) {
var myData = JSON.parse([e.postData.contents]);
  var timestamp = new Date();
  var order_number = myData.number;
  var parent_id= myData.parent_id;
  var order_status = myData.status;
  var billing_first_name = myData.billing.first_name;
  var billing_last_name = myData.billing.last_name;
  var billing_phone = myData.billing.phone;
  var billing_email = myData.billing.email;
  var order_total = myData.total;
  var billing_address_1 = myData.billing.address_1;
  var billing_address_2 = myData.billing.address_2;
  var billing_city = myData.billing.city;
  var billing_address = billing_address_1 + ", " + billing_address_2 + ", " + billing_city;
  var billing_postcode = myData.billing.postcode;
  var shipping_first_name = myData.shipping.first_name;
  var shipping_last_name = myData.shipping.last_name;
  var shipping_address_1 = myData.shipping.address_1;
  var shipping_address_2 = myData.shipping.address_2;
  var shipping_city = myData.shipping.city;
  var shipping_address = shipping_address_1 + ", " + shipping_address_2 + ", " + shipping_city;
  var shipping_postcode = myData.shipping.postcode;

  var lineitems=""
  for (i in myData.line_items)
  {
    var product_name       = myData.line_items[i].name;
    var itemName = myData.line_items[i].name;
    var quantity = myData.line_items[i].quantity;
    var linetotal = myData.line_items[i].total;
    var product_items      = quantity + " x " + itemName + ": £"+linetotal +"\n"; 
    var lineitems =lineitems+product_items;
  }

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  sheet.appendRow([timestamp,order_number,parent_id,order_status,billing_first_name,billing_last_name,billing_phone,billing_email,lineitems,order_total,billing_address,billing_postcode,shipping_first_name,shipping_last_name,shipping_address,shipping_postcode]);
}
```

---

Answer (score 1):

What is missing from your question is:

- We don't know from from where and how you get the order data in javascript
- We don't know where you need to display the order Number.

So we can only make a generic answer.

*Also note that asking multiple questions at once is not allowed in StackOverFlow*.

---

1) The WooCommerce add-ons data within an WooCommerce order is stored as order item custom meta data:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

// The loop to get the order items which are WC_Order_Item_Product objects since WC 3+
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ){

    // Get the special meta data in an array: 
    $meta_data = $item->get_meta_data();

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($meta_data); echo '<pre>'; // Testing raw output

    // Get all additional meta data (formatted in an unprotected array)
    $formatted_meta_data = $item->get_formatted_meta_data( ' ', true );

    echo '<pre>'; print_r($formatted_meta_data); echo '<pre>'; // Testing raw output

    // Get the specific meta data from a meta_key: 
    $meta_value = $item->get_meta( 'custom_meta_key' );
}
```

Related: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

---

2) To get the parent order number from a subscription you will use:

- From the subscription ID we can get the order ID very easily:

  ```
  $order_id = wp_get_post_parent_id( $subscription_id );
  ```
- From a `WC_Subscription` Object we can also get the order ID very easily:

  ```
  $order_id = $subscription->get_parent_id();
  ```

Then from this order ID you can get the order number with:

```
// Get an instance of the WC_Order object
$order = wc_get_order( $order_id );

$order_mumber = $order->get_order_number();
```

or with:

```
$order_mumber = get_post_meta( $order_id, _order_number, true );
```