# Get non formatted value from $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal() in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, price

I need to make certain changes to the file order-details-item.php Product prices are formed in custom meta fields. So in my case the value is: $qty   = $item->get_quantity(); is incorrect. It is always the same.

To solve the problem, I can use the simplest arephmetic operation. Divide the total order price by the product price. For example, if a customer ordered 10 kilograms of apples at a cost of 14.5 per kilogram the total cost will be 145. This means that in order to correctly display the quantity I need 145/10.

```
    $price_weight_array = $product_attr['_mia_cup_price_weight'];
    $price_unit_array = $product_attr['_mia_cup_price_unit'];
    $sale_price_array = $product_attr['_mia_cup_sale_price_unit'];  
    
    $price_weight = $price_weight_array[0];
    $price_unit   = $price_unit_array[0];
    $sale_price = $sale_price_array[0];
    $prod_item_total = $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal();

    custom_quantity = $prod_item_total / $price_weight
```

And here is the problem $order->get_formatted_line_subtotal(); returns me a number with currency symbol. And I cannot use it in arithmetic operation. How can I remove this symbol?

Comment: First code is incomplete and not reproducible, remember that your *"question should be updated to include desired behavior, a specific problem or error, and **the shortest code necessary to reproduce the problem"***. Also the method `get_formatted_line_subtotal()` requires a mandatory argument `$item` which is the `WC_Order_Item_Product` Object and so in your code it throw an error… For order "line" items see [*Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incomplete and you are not using the right way… Also [`get_formatted_line_subtotal()` method](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.6.1/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L1857) requires a mandatory argument in order to work and as you know displays the **formatted** order item subtotal *(with currency symbol)*…

Based on *[How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)* and *[Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)*, you need first to get order items and you will use your code in a foreach loop.

To get the non formatted and non rounded order item subtotal you will use instead [get_line_subtotal()](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/4.6.1/includes/abstracts/abstract-wc-order.php#L1760) method as follows:

```
$order = wc_get_order($order_id); // (optional - if needed) get the WC_Order object

// Loop through order items
foreach( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item ) {
    $product = $item->get_product(); // get the WC_Product Object

    // Your other code (missing from your question) Here …

    $price_weight    = reset($product_attr['_mia_cup_price_weight']);
    $price_unit      = reset($product_attr['_mia_cup_price_unit']);
    $sale_price_unit = reset($product_attr['_mia_cup_sale_price_unit']); 

    // Get the non formatted order item subtotal (and not rounded)
    $item_subtotal   = $order->get_line_subtotal( $item, $order->get_prices_include_tax(), false );

    $custom_quantity = $item_subtotal / $price_weight;
}
```

It should better work