# Set some WooCommerce Order and Order item data in a custom array

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

I’m trying to implement sending notifications in telegram in functions.php my theme…

All data is sent except product details, here is the code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'telegram_notification',  1, 1  );
function telegram_notification( $order_id ) {

            $order = wc_get_order( $order_id );
        $order_data = $order->get_data(); // The Order data 
        
        
$order_id = $order_data['id'];
$order_payment_method_title = $order_data['payment_method_title'];

## Creation and modified WC_DateTime Object date string ##

// Using a formated date ( with php date() function as method)
$order_date_created = $order_data['date_created']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
$order_date_modified = $order_data['date_modified']->date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

$order_currency = $order_data['currency'];
$order_shipping_method = $order_data['shipping_method'];

$order_total = $order_data['total'];

## BILLING INFORMATION:

$order_billing_first_name = $order_data['billing']['first_name'];
$order_billing_last_name = $order_data['billing']['last_name'];
$order_billing_address_1 = $order_data['billing']['address_1'];
$order_billing_address_2 = $order_data['billing']['address_2'];
$order_billing_city = $order_data['billing']['city'];
$order_billing_state = $order_data['billing']['state'];
$order_billing_postcode = $order_data['billing']['postcode'];
$order_billing_country = $order_data['billing']['country'];
$order_billing_email = $order_data['billing']['email'];
$order_billing_phone = $order_data['billing']['phone'];

## SHIPPING INFORMATION:

   // data to send to third party
$product_name = '';
$product_sku = '';

// Iterating through each WC_Order_Item_Product objects
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item_key => $item ):

    ## Using WC_Order_Item methods ##

    // Item ID is directly accessible from the $item_key in the foreach loop or
    $item_id = $item->get_id();

    ## Using WC_Order_Item_Product methods ##

    $product      = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object

    $product_id   = $item->get_product_id(); // the Product id
    $variation_id = $item->get_variation_id(); // the Variation id

    $item_type    = $item->get_type(); // Type of the order item ("line_item")

    $item_name    = $item->get_name(); // Name of the product
    $quantity     = $item->get_quantity();  
    $tax_class    = $item->get_tax_class();
    $line_subtotal     = $item->get_subtotal(); // Line subtotal (non discounted)
    $line_subtotal_tax = $item->get_subtotal_tax(); // Line subtotal tax (non discounted)
    $line_total        = $item->get_total(); // Line total (discounted)
    $line_total_tax    = $item->get_total_tax(); // Line total tax (discounted)

    ## Access Order Items data properties (in an array of values) ##
    $item_data    = $item->get_data();

    $product_name = $item_data['name'];
    $product_id   = $item_data['product_id'];
    $variation_id = $item_data['variation_id'];
    $quantity     = $item_data['quantity'];
    $tax_class    = $item_data['tax_class'];
    $line_subtotal     = $item_data['subtotal'];
    $line_subtotal_tax = $item_data['subtotal_tax'];
    $line_total        = $item_data['total'];
    $line_total_tax    = $item_data['total_tax'];

    // Get data from The WC_product object using methods (examples)
    $product        = $item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product object

    $product_type   = $product->get_type();
    $product_sku    = $product->get_sku();
    $product_price  = $product->get_price();
    $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();

endforeach;
        

//Далее создаем переменную, в которую помещаем PHP массив
$arr = array(
  'Номер заказа: ' => $order_id,
  'Дата: ' => $order_date_modified,
  'Название товара: ' => $product_name,
  'Артикул: ' => $product_sku,
  'Мета продукта:' => $somemeta,
  'Цена товара: ' => $order_total,
  'Валюта: ' => $order_currency,
  'Имя: ' => $order_billing_first_name,
  'Фамилия: ' => $order_billing_last_name,
  'Телефон: ' => $order_billing_phone,
  'Email: ' => $order_billing_email,
  'Страна: ' => $order_billing_country,
  'Область: ' => $order_billing_state,
  'Город: ' => $order_billing_city,
  'Адрес1: ' => $order_billing_address_1,
  'Адрес2: ' => $order_billing_address_2,
  'Индекс: ' => $order_billing_postcode,
  'Метод доставки: ' => $order_shipping_method,
  'Метод оплаты: ' => $order_payment_method_title
);

//При помощи цикла перебираем массив и помещаем переменную $txt текст из массива $arr
foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
  $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
};
```

and send to privat chat.

What am I doing wrong?

As I understand it, it just doesn't work to get data from foreach into $ arr.

I'm not good at programming, so I ask for help to figure it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Updated**

You can have many order items in an Order, but as it seem you need to get only the first order item use the following instead:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_new_order', 'telegram_notification',  1, 1  );
function telegram_notification( $order_id ) {
    $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); // Get the WC_Order Object

    $order_items = $order->get_items(); // Get order items array

    $order_item  = reset($order_items); // Keep the first order item
    
    $product     = $order_item->get_product(); // Get the WC_Product Object

    $somemeta    = ''; // <== To be defined !!!
    $txt         = ''; // Initializing

    // Add all order related data to our custom indexed array
    $arr = array(
        'Номер заказа: '    => $order_id,
        'Дата: '            => $order->get_date_modified()->date('Y-m-d H:i:s'),
        'Название товара: ' => $order_item->get_name(),
        'Артикул: '         => $product->get_sku(),
        'Мета продукта:'    => $somemeta, // ! Not defined
        'Цена товара: '     => $order->get_total(),
        'Валюта: '          => $order->get_currency(),
        'Имя: '             => $order->get_billing_first_name(),
        'Фамилия: '         => $order->get_billing_last_name(),
        'Телефон: '         => $order->get_billing_phone(),
        'Email: '           => $order->get_billing_email(),
        'Страна: '          => $order->get_billing_country(),
        'Область: '         => $order->get_billing_state(),
        'Город: '           => $order->get_billing_city(),
        'Адрес1: '          => $order->get_billing_address_1(),
        'Адрес2: '          => $order->get_billing_address_2(),
        'Индекс: '          => $order->get_billing_postcode(),
        'Метод доставки: '  => $order->get_shipping_method(),
        'Метод оплаты: '    => $order->get_payment_method_title() // Updated
    );

    // Loop through the data array to convert it as a string to be sent by SMS
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
    };

    // Other code to send The SMS from $txt string variable
}
```

Tested and works…

Related:

- [How to get WooCommerce order details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39401393/how-to-get-woocommerce-order-details/44708344#44708344)
- [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Unfortunately, the above code doesn't work. On the checkout page, no data is sent at all, an error pops up without text and that's it.

Ideally, of course, receive all the goods from the order, I just don't understand what I'm doing wrong ...

Comment: Woocommerce Logs: CRITICAL Uncaught Error: Call to a member function get_product() on boolean in

Comment: The error remains. Perhaps I am not sending data correctly to telegram?    
 
 // Loop through the data array to convert it as a string to be sent by SMS
    foreach($arr as $key => $value) {
        $txt .= "<b>".$key."</b> ".$value."%0A";
    };
$xsl = file_get_contents("https://api.telegram.org/botxxx/sendMessage?parse_mode=html&chat_id=-xxx&text=" . $txt);

Comment: @СтаниславВоропаев the data array is correctly set and works… Now I don't know about your SMS API (you should better ask their support)…