# Filtering the WooCommerce $order items by Category (term)

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, array-filter

In this problem, I have all the pieces but I just can't seem to get them to fit together.

I have a printing template for WooCommerce orders that lists the products in the normal way, the order they are stored in the array which in turn is the order they were placed in the basket etc.  However, we want them grouped by Category (Term).  So this will mean that all items under *term_id 17* are listed first, then all *term_id 18*, etc.

Ideally, this would be an automatic process where the code reads all of the Terms in use, then steps through them one at a time and outputs any products for that Term that are in the basket.  But I'm nowhere near that stage yet.

So far I have had partial success with this code:

```
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {

     $product_id = $item['product_id'];

     $meta = $item['item_meta'];
     $meta = array_filter($meta, function ($key) {
     return !in_array($key, Order::getHiddenKeys());
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);

$terms = get_the_terms ( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
    $cat_id = $term->term_id;
    
    if($cat_id === 18) {
        var_dump($item['name']);
    }
}
```

This will successfully dump the order items that are categorised in *term_id 18*.  However, if I modify the IF statement like this:

```
if($cat_id === 18) {
    var_dump($item['name']);
} elseif($cat_id === 17) {
    var_dump($item['name']);
}
```

I would have expected it to output the *term_id 18* items, then the *term_id 17* ones **AFTER** them.  Unfortunately, it simply shows the array in the default order of 17, then 18, despite the fact the code is laid out in this fashion.

I thought that maybe it was outputting in this way because it's not modifying the original array, simply masking parts of it at different points.  So, I have been experimenting with the *array_filter* function, but I can't seem the get the logic right.  I know this attempt is awful, but this is as far as I've gotten experimenting with *array_filter*:

```
function test ($var) {
    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        $cat_id = $term->term_id;
    
        if($cat_id === 18) {
            print_r($item['name']);
        }
    }
    return $var;
}
    
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {

    $product_id = $item['product_id'];

    $meta = $item['item_meta'];
    $meta = array_filter($meta, function ($key) {
    return !in_array($key, Order::getHiddenKeys());
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
    
$terms = get_the_terms ( $product_id, 'product_cat' );

print_r(array_filter($terms, "test"));
```

I know it's significantly wrong, but I just can't get my head around it. I'm fine with basic PHP and WordPress PHP usage normally, but WooCommerce is so much more complicated!

Just to recap, I want the products in the order printed / echoed / etc in Category Order (ideally automatically).  I don't really mind how this is achieved so long as it's safe and secure obviously.

Comment: Your code is a bit obsolete since WooCommerce 3 look to [this thread for order items](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45706318/3730754) in the loop... Now sorting order items based on product category is tricky as you can have many categories set for a product… A better way is to sort cart items before placing an order *([see this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65801029/3730754))*

Comment: I was aware it wasn't the greatest approach since the move to Woocommerce 3, but I've been struggling to find code examples along the lines I've been looking for hence why I've wound up with this approach.  In particular the sorting by category aspect.

I'll certainly have a read of the threads you've highlighted though but at the moment sorting in the cart is a backup plan as I'm interfacing with a third party and can't guarentee nothing interferes with it before it gets to this point, hence this approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like you're looping the orders, but you're not looping the categories you want to be ordering them.

I've not run this code, but the pattern should do what you want I think.

```
// Group items into Categories - If you have a custom order you wish, pre-populate this array, or you can sort after
$categories = [];
foreach ($order->get_items() as $item) {
    $product_id = $item['product_id'];
    $terms = get_the_terms($product_id, 'product_cat');
    $cat_id = $terms[0]->term_id;
    $categories[$cat_id][] = $item;
}

// Loop Categories
foreach($categories as $category => $items){
    echo sprintf("<h1>%s</h1>", $category);
    //Loop Items in Category
    foreach ($items as $item) {
        print_r($item['name']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, this is almost there!  It's listing the category ID then the contents, just 5 times, which is the number of items in the order.

I'm going to have a proper pick through this in the morning and see if I can fine-tune it.

Comment: No, ignore that, it was me being dumb.  I accidently placed it inside another loop!  This code works perfectly.

Comment: One thing before I mark it as the accepted answer.  How easy is it to adjust the ordering of the categories with this approach?

If I'm reading this right you could just change the $categories variable to a list of integers and it'd work so long as you removed the line assigning $cat_id to $categories.

Comment: If the categories are set, and you're happy to hard code it, then if you set the $categories array upfront, that's all you need to do. e.g. the following would set the order to 18,17, and then anything else would follow afterwards - $categories = [18=>[], 17=>[]];

Comment: Alternatively, if you just wanted to sort by category name, then before you loop categories you could do a Key Sort - ksort($categories) for ASC and krsort($categories) for DESC

Comment: That's pretty much what I thought, thanks for clarifying that.  At present this usage should be absolutely perfect, but I just wanted to double-check my options whilst we were talking about it.

Thanks again bud!