# Sort specific product category cart items at the end in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, taxonomy-terms

How to sort items from a defined product category to be at the end of a cart order, for example I want all products that belong to a product category 'bottle' to be at the end of the cart order.

I have found this code that sorts by price, but would like to adjust to as described above.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'prefix_cart_order_prod_cat' );

function prefix_cart_order_prod_cat() {

    $products_in_cart = array();
    // Assign each product's price to its cart item key (to be used again later)
    foreach ( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item ) {
        $product = wc_get_product( $item['product_id'] );
        $products_in_cart[ $key ] = $product->get_price();
    }

    // SORTING - use one or the other two following lines:
    //asort( $products_in_cart ); // sort low to high
   arsort( $products_in_cart ); // sort high to low

    // Put sorted items back in cart
    $cart_contents = array();
    foreach ( $products_in_cart as $cart_key => $price ) {
       $cart_contents[ $cart_key ] = WC()->cart->cart_contents[ $cart_key ];
    }

    WC()->cart->cart_contents = $cart_contents;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`has_term()` conditional WordPress function](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/has_term/) to check if cart items belongs to a product category *(but the defined category(ies) need to be set for the related products (items))*.

So the following code will sort cart items with items belonging to specified category(ies) at the end:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_cart_loaded_from_session', 'product_category_cart_items_sorted_end' );
function product_category_cart_items_sorted_end() {
    $category_terms    = __('T-shirts'); // Here set your category terms (can be names, slugs or Ids)
    $items_in_category = $other_items = array(); // Initizlizing

    // Assign each item in a different array depending if it belongs to defined category terms or not
    foreach ( WC()->cart->cart_contents as $key => $item ) {
        if( has_term( $category_terms, 'product_cat', $item['product_id'] ) ) {
            $items_in_category[ $key ] = $item;
        } else {
            $other_items[ $key ] = $item;
        }
    }

    // Set back merged items arrays with the items that belongs to a category at the end
    WC()->cart->cart_contents = array_merge( $other_items, $items_in_category );
}
```

Code goes in functions.php file of the active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.