# WooCommerce order items: Check if a variation is a child of specific variable product

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, product-variations

I'm trying to calculate how many variations with unique parent-product id are inside an order.

For example this my order:

```
Product A: Size: Small, Color: Red
Product A: Size Medium, Color: Blue

Product B: Size: Small, Color: Yellow
Product B: Size: Large, Color Blue
```

I want to calculate how many unique products exist in the order (in this case 2, A & B), and how many variables exist in each unique product (in this case 2 each).

How can I do this?

I tried something with this code, but I got stuck...

```
    $order_id       = $order->get_id();
    $order_number   = $order->get_order_number();
    $order_quantity = $order->get_item_count();
    
    # Iterating through each order items (WC_Order_Item_Product objects in WC 3+)
    foreach ( $order_id->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values ) {

    // Product_id
    $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id(); 
    
    // For product variation type
    if( $item_values->is_type('variation') ){
    if( $item_values->get_variation_id() > 0 ){
    for ($x = 0; $x < $item_values->get_variation_id(); $x++) {
        
    }
        // Get the instance of the parent variable product Object
        $parent_product = wc_get_product( $item->get_product_id() );
```

Answer (score 2):

When you have an order item **that is a product variation** the `WC_Order_Item_Product` methods:

- `get_variation_id()` gives the variation ID, **an integer always higher than zero**.
- `get_product_id()` gives the parent variable product ID

To get the product counts from your code as you would like, use something like:

```
$count_products = array();

foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) {
    if ( $item->get_variation_id() > 0 ) {
        if( isset($count[$item->get_product_id()]) {
             $count_products[$item->get_product_id()] += 1;
        } else {
             $count_products[$item->get_product_id()] = 1;
        }
    }
}

echo '<p>Variable products count: ' . count($count_products) . '</p>';

echo '<div>Variations count for each variable product:<br><ul>';
foreach( $count_products as $parent_id => $count ) {
    echo '<li>Variable product Id ' . $parent_id . ' has ' . $count . 'Variation' . _n('', 's', $count) . '</li>';
}
echo '</ul></div>';
```

Now if you want to count quantities you will use `WC_Order_Item_Product` method `get_quantity()`.

Related: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Answer (score 1):

maybe this code can help to you

```
$order_id       = $order->get_id();
$order_number   = $order->get_order_number();
$order_quantity = $order->get_item_count();
$count=[];
# Iterating through each order items (WC_Order_Item_Product objects in WC 3+)
foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item_id => $item_values ) {
    //$product_name = $item_values->get_name();
    $product_id = $item_values->get_product_id();
    $product_variation_id = $item_values->get_variation_id();
    $count['parent'][$product_id]+= 1;
    if($product_variation_id >0 ){
        $count['child'][$product_id][$product_variation_id] += 1;
    }
}
print_r ($count);
```

output :

```
[parent] => Array
    [
        [57] => 2
        [56] => 2
    ]

[child] => Array
    [
        [56] => Array
            [
                [61] => 1,
                [68] => 1,
            ],
        [57] => Array
            [
                [82] => 1,
                [89]=> 1,
            ]
    ]
```

Let me know if you have any question ;)