# What is the WooCommerce hook to for purchases details after checkout?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, orders

Does anyone knows what is the hook in WooCommerce to get all the purchase details when you checkout?

I can not find it anywhere.

Comment: You may want to check the WooCommerce hooks reference for this information - it lists all hooks: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/hooks/hooks.html

`woocommerce_after_checkout_validation` seems promising. This is not submitted as an answer as I am not certain this is what you need or want based on your question - you may want to clarify your intentions as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hook that you are looking at is `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item`, located in [`WC_Checkout` method `create_order_line_items()`](https://github.com/woocommerce/woocommerce/blob/5.0.0/includes/class-wc-checkout.php#L443-L494)

The `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook allows to adjust line item before save. It has 4 defined arguments:

- `$item` is the `WC_Order_Item_Product` object
- `$cart_item_key` is the related cart item key
- `$values` is the related cart item
- `$order` is the `WC_Order` Object

[All StackOverFlow treads using `woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item` action hook](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=woocommerce_checkout_create_order_line_item).

Related: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)