# Get last product from an order in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, product, orders

Is it possible to get only latest product of woocommerce order?
I know that is possible for notes as example:

```
// Get last order note
    $latest_notes = wc_get_order_notes( array(
        'order_id' => $order->get_id(),
        'limit'    => 1,
        'orderby'  => 'date_created_gmt',
    ) );

    $latest_note = current( $latest_notes );
```

Can I make something similar for products inside order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the latest product from a `WC_Order` Object, you can use `end()` function from order items array, like:

```
$order_items = $order->get_items(); // Get order items
$last_item   = end($order_items); // Latest WC_Order_Item_Product Object instance
$product     = $last_item->get_product(); // Latest WC_Product Object instance
```

Related: [Get Order items and WC_Order_Item_Product in WooCommerce 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45706007/get-order-items-and-wc-order-item-product-in-woocommerce-3/45706318#45706318)

Comment: Thank you @loictheaztec.
So if i use `$last_item = reset($order_items);`

Should get first one?

Comment: @ВладимирКятипов The first one is `reset($order_items);` or `current($order_items);`.